# TFS - Continuous integration with branching

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs

Here is my scenario (**TFS Online - username.visualstudio.com/repo**):

I have a following folder structure

```
--$
  --TimeManagement  (.sln file at this level)
    --WebApp  (Main branch) (.csproj at this level)
    --WebApp-Dev (Dev Branch) (.csproj at this level)
    --WebApp-QA (QA Branch) (.csproj at this level)
    --TestTimeManagement (Test Project)
```

With this, I create a build with default settings and my release option pushes success build to azure web site. This works perfect until I come with following scenarios:

- I would need same/only test project configured for main & Dev branch
- I need to have branch change specific build, so instead of `.sln` file, I want build should consider `.csproj` of branch.
- I can make changes under each build's trigger tab - continuous build - add filter with branch specific folders
- In this case, My **dev** branch changes will mostly execute build related and execute test & when I finally merge my changes to **main**  branch, build related to it will execute with same test case.
- I tried to play around this, however, build was getting messed up with `.csproj` to solution option. It is not able to find test assembly - `**\*test*.dll`

In simple words, I am looking for setting up TFS (online, at this moment) where there will be multiple branches (dev, main, staging, qa) with single test project and configure builds, triggers on specific branch changes.

> Doubt: Can we create branch at `.csproj` level or only need branching at `.sln` level?

If I get any reference doc/video, would be great !

Comment: Why can't you just branch at the solution level?

Comment: That can be done anytime and workable. I wanted to know the scenario I am trying is feasible or completely out of box. To avoid repetitive code/projects across solution.

Comment: Always branch at the solution level. What you suggest is almost always a bad idea.

Comment: @Fran, MrHinsh, Yes I understood this, however was trying to understand feasibility.

Comment: you've seen the issues with branching at the project level.  if the projects need to be independently versioned i'd put them in there own solution and version them separately.  I also question only 1 test project for 3 separate projects.  you should have a test project per branch because there will be branch specific info, codes, ... that needs to be tested independently.

Comment: as well as nuget package changes between branches.  those are kept at the solution level if you are checking in the packages.  could be different per branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Doubt: Can we create branch at .csproj level or only need branching at .sln level?

You can branch at any level you want: Solution level, project level, folder level and file level.

I have a set-up where we have multiple solutions and there are multiple projects that are either used by one solution or shared by multiple. If they are shared by multiple solutions and you make changes to the project when working on one solution, there is a possibility you may potentially break other solutions. Therefore, for this case, I have a [master](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668953.aspx) solution which has a CI build that builds all the projects to make sure nothing is broken.

Keep in mind, when you have many branches, merging becomes more complicated. I suggest you start with a simple 2 branch strategy: Dev and Main branch. If this does not work for you, then create more branches. Every day development can be done on the Dev branch, and when you are ready you can cut-off and go to Main branch. But before you merge to Main, make sure to merge up from Main branch to Dev and then merge down from Dev to Main: Always do this as a good practice.

There is a difference between environments (Dev, QA, Prod) and branches. The relationship need not be 1:1. So you can have 2 branches (Dev, Main) and still have many different environments.

Comment: @CondingYoshi, I agree to your point. Just a question, as you are also have same implementation of projects shared across multiple solutions. Is this dependency - reference add, done thru MSBuild in TFS? I was trying add mutple projects in build, however this works fine at local machine, references can add and find easily, however on TFS MSBuild level, references are not able to find, Any suggestions?

Comment: In VSTS (web portal of TFS), you need to make sure in the `Repository` tab, in the server path you have not specified only the project you are building. You have to specify a location so when the files are downloaded from that location, all the dependencies are downloaded as well.

Comment: I think, I need to look more into these options.

Comment: Treat the Repository tab the same as when you are getting stuff on the dev machine (get latest). It is the same idea. Actually it is exactly the same because the build server will get the latest and then try to build it. Like a developer.

Comment: Last but not least, Is there way, where I can restrict checkin for successful unit test/ test case execution at Visual Studio level?

Comment: Look into gated checkins, that way if the test fails on the build server it will reject the checkin. You can also configure it to reject if compilation fails. But please read up on that because of you have a large team then their checkins will get queued up and they will not get reply right away if their checkin went through or not. I suggest you create a playground collection and experiment there. Your whole team can play there without restrictions

Comment: Just now I configured few things, on my local machine, add **check-in policies** for *1. Successful build* , *2. Code analysis* and also enable *enable code analysis*  on project properties level. This is restricts my check-in if *build fails* or *unit test fails*.